# Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject' does not contain a property

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik

I got this strange error when i want to bind something in my grid from my db 
I've been trying to find the workaround for the following problem for the last couple of hours, but without any success. I've found many of the possible solutions on the Internet, but none of them was solution to my problem.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ABBMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="UserEditPanel.aspx.cs" Inherits="HolidayTracker.Administrator.UserEditPanel" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainRegionContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="rsmTelerik" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>


    <br />
    <%-- Export script %>
    <%--    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onRequestStart(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToExcelButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToWordButton") >= 0 ||
                    args.get_eventTarget().indexOf("ExportToCsvButton") >= 0) {
                args.set_enableAjax(false);
            }
        }
    </script>--%>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent" CssClass="pnlContent" runat="server">

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeader" CssClass="pnlHeader" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlBody" CssClass="pnlBody" runat="server">
            <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Default" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                <fieldset style="padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <legend>User form</legend>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <asp:Label ID="label4" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>

                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbSearch" CssClass="rowForm" runat="server" Width="260px"
                            Height="100px" EmptyMessage="Enter Email" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="true" AllowCustomText="true" MarkFirstMatch="true"
                            OnItemsRequested="rcbSearch_ItemsRequested" CausesValidation="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcbSearch_IndexChanged" Skin="Default">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rcbSearch"
                            ValidationExpression="^[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}){1,2}$"
                            ErrorMessage="Enter a valid email address" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rcbSearch"
                            ErrorMessage="Can not be empty" CssClass="rowFormValidation" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="Firstname"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbFirstName" CssClass="rowForm" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rtbFirstName"
                            ErrorMessage="Can not be empty" CssClass="rowFormValidation" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <asp:Label ID="label2" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="Lastname"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbLastName" CssClass="rowForm" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLastName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rtbLastName"
                            ErrorMessage="Can not be empty" CssClass="rowFormValidation" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <asp:Label ID="label3" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbUserName" CssClass="rowForm" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rtbUserName"
                            ErrorMessage="Can not be empty" CssClass="rowFormValidation" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv" style="display: none;">
                        <asp:Label ID="label5" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="AdAccount"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbAdAccount" CssClass="rowForm" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv" style="display: none;">
                        <asp:Label ID="label6" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="AdDomain"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbAdDomain" CssClass="rowForm" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" Text="Role" CssClass="formLabel"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbUserRoles" CssClass="rowForm" CheckBoxes="True" EmptyMessage="- Please select -"
                            runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="RoleId">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserRoleSqlSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [HtUserRole]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <%--  <asp:Label ID="label7" CssClass="formLabel" runat="server" Text="Annual vacations"></asp:Label> --%>
                        <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel2" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">

                            <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgAnnualVacation" runat="server" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True"
                                OnInsertCommand="rgAnnualVacation_InsertCommand" OnDeleteCommand="rgAnnualVacation_DeleteCommand" Height="200px"
                                OnUpdateCommand="rgAnnualVacation_UpdateCommand" OnNeedDataSource="rgAnnualVacation_NeedDataSource">

                                <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="AnnualVacationId" CommandItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">

                                    <Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AnnualVacationId" Visible="false" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter AnnualVacationId column" HeaderText="AnnualVacationId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AnnualVacationId" UniqueName="AnnualVacationId">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserId" Visible="false" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter UserId column" HeaderText="UserId" SortExpression="UserId" UniqueName="UserId">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FromDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter FromDate column" HeaderText="FromDate" SortExpression="FromDate" UniqueName="FromDate">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ToDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter ToDate column" HeaderText="ToDate" SortExpression="ToDate" UniqueName="ToDate">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="WorkingTime" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter WorkingTime column" HeaderText="WorkingTime" SortExpression="WorkingTime" UniqueName="WorkingTime">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VacationDays" DataType="System.Double" FilterControlAltText="Filter VacationDays column" HeaderText="VacationDays" SortExpression="VacationDays" UniqueName="VacationDays">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn />
                                    </Columns>

                                    <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
                                        <FormTemplate>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>From</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="fromdatepicker" runat="server" MaxDate="1/1/2015" DbSelectedDate='<%# Eval("fromdate") == null ? null : Eval("fromdate") %>' TabIndex="4">
                                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>To</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="todatepicker" runat="server" MinDate="1/1/1900" DbSelectedDate='<%# Eval("todate") == null ? null :Eval("todate")%>'
                                                            TabIndex="4">
                                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Working time (%)</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtWorkingTime" runat="server" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" DbValue='<%# Bind("WorkingTime") %>'></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>Vacation days</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtVacationDays" runat="server" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" DbValue='<%# Bind("VacationDays") %>'></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <table style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                                            runat="server" CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>'></asp:Button>&nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                                            CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </FormTemplate>
                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                    <%--<CommandItemSettings ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" ShowExportToCsvButton="true" />--%>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
                                </FilterMenu>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
                        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formRowDiv">
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="rbBack" CssClass="rowButton" runat="server" Text="Back" OnClick="rbBack_Clicked"
                            CausesValidation="false" />
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="rbSave" CssClass="rowButton" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="rbSave_Clicked" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
            <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Default">
            </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlFooter" CssClass="pnlFooter" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>






using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HolidayTracker.Data.Model;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using HolidayTracker.Code;
using System.Collections;

namespace HolidayTracker.Administrator
{
    public partial class UserEditPanel : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        private List<AnnualVacation> annualVacations = new List<AnnualVacation>();

        private Boolean newUser;
        private HtUser paramUser;
        private HtUser user;
        private HtUser User
        {
            get
            {
                user = HtUser.INIT_USER(this.Page, true);
                return user;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getParameters();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                bindData();

                fillFieldsWithData();
                initFieldSettings();
            }
        }

        private void getParameters()
        {
            if (Page.Request["userId"] != null)
            {
                int userId = Constants.TryConvert(Page.Request["userId"], this.Page);
                this.paramUser = HtUser.GetById(userId);
            }
            else
            {
                this.paramUser = new HtUser();
            }
        }

        private void initFieldSettings()
        {
            if (!newUser)
            {
                //this.rcbSearch.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void bindData()
        {
            this.rcbUserRoles.DataSource = this.UserRoleSqlSource;
            this.rcbUserRoles.DataBind();

            //fill viewstate with annual vacations if empty
            if (paramUser != null && paramUser.AnnualVacations.Any())
            {
                if (ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"] == null)
                {
                    annualVacations.AddRange(paramUser.AnnualVacations);
                    ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"] = annualVacations;
                }
            }
        }

        private void fillFieldsWithData()
        {
            if (paramUser != null)
            {
                this.rtbFirstName.Text = paramUser.FirstName;
                this.rtbLastName.Text = paramUser.LastName;
                this.rtbUserName.Text = paramUser.UserName;
                this.rcbSearch.Text = paramUser.Email;
                this.rtbAdAccount.Text = paramUser.AdAccount;
                this.rtbAdDomain.Text = paramUser.AdDomain;

                //UserRole
                IEnumerable<HtUserRole> userRoles = paramUser.HtUserRoles != null ? paramUser.HtUserRoles : null;
                if (userRoles != null && userRoles.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (RadComboBoxItem rcbi in rcbUserRoles.Items)
                    {
                        rcbi.Checked = false;
                        foreach (HtUserRole ur in userRoles)
                        {
                            if (ur.RoleId.ToString() == rcbi.Value)
                            {
                                rcbi.Checked = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void rcbSearch_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Text != null && e.Text.Length > 2)
            {
                IEnumerable<HtUser> result = null;
                AdLookup lookup = new AdLookup();
                result = lookup.SearchAdUserByEmail(e.Text);//HtUser.SearchByEmail(e.Text);
                if (result != null && result.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (HtUser user in result)
                    {
                        this.rcbSearch.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(user.Email, user.UserId.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void rcbSearch_IndexChanged(object sneder, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string email = e.Text;
            AdLookup lookup = new AdLookup();
            paramUser = lookup.GetAdUserByEmail(email);
            fillFieldsWithData();
        }

        private void saveData()
        {
            HolidayTrackerEntities ctx = HtEntityFactory.Context;
            HtUser userToSave = ctx.HtUsers.Where(u => u.UserId == paramUser.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (userToSave == null)
            {
                userToSave = new HtUser();
                userToSave.IsNew = true;
            }
            userToSave.FirstName = this.rtbFirstName.Text;
            userToSave.LastName = this.rtbLastName.Text;
            userToSave.UserName = this.rtbUserName.Text;
            userToSave.Email = this.rcbSearch.Text;
            userToSave.AdAccount = this.rtbAdAccount.Text;
            userToSave.AdDomain = this.rtbAdDomain.Text;

            //UserRole
            foreach (RadComboBoxItem rcbi in rcbUserRoles.Items)
            {
                HtUserRole newUserRole = HtUserRole.GetById(int.Parse(rcbi.Value));

                if (rcbi.Checked)
                {
                    if (userToSave.HtUserRoles.Where(x => x.RoleId == newUserRole.RoleId).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        userToSave.HtUserRoles.Add(newUserRole);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (userToSave.HtUserRoles.Where(x => x.RoleId == newUserRole.RoleId).Count() > 0)
                    {
                        userToSave.HtUserRoles.Remove(newUserRole);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (userToSave.IsNew)
            {
                ctx.AddToHtUsers(userToSave);
            }

            if (((List<AnnualVacation>)ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"]) != null)
            {
                List<AnnualVacation> vacationToSave = (List<AnnualVacation>)ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"];
                IEnumerable<AnnualVacation> existing = paramUser.AnnualVacations;
                foreach (AnnualVacation toSave in vacationToSave)
                {
                    //if (toSave.IsNew) {
                    //    ctx.AddToAnnualVacations(toSave);
                    //}

                    //Zu löschende aus context löschen
                }
            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        protected void rbBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Administrator/UserPanel.aspx");
        }

        protected void rbSave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveData();
            fillFieldsWithData();
        }

        protected void rgAnnualVacation_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
                Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
                item.ExtractValues(values);

                AnnualVacation newAnnualVacation = new AnnualVacation();
                item.UpdateValues(newAnnualVacation);
                //newAnnualVacation.IsNew = true;

                ((List<AnnualVacation>)ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"]).Add(newAnnualVacation);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Hier fehlermeldung
            }

        }

        protected void rgAnnualVacation_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int annualVacationId = int.Parse((e.Item as GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("AnnualVacationId").ToString());
            ((List<AnnualVacation>)ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"]).
                Remove(((List<AnnualVacation>)ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"]).
                Where(av => av.AnnualVacationId == annualVacationId).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        protected void rgAnnualVacation_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            rgAnnualVacation.DataSource = ViewState["AnnualVacationSource"];
            if (rgAnnualVacation.DataSource == null)
            {
                rgAnnualVacation.DataSource = String.Empty;
            }
        }

        protected void rgAnnualVacation_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show complete error message and when it's fired...looking at your code, everything seems fine. (Complete message should include the name of the missing property...which realy helps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe datafields `fromdate` and `todate` are case sensitive. I see your GridBoundColumns use `FromDate` and `ToDate`.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This is freaky, try adding an empty Page_DataBinding event handler to your insert/edit UserControl:

```
Private Sub Page_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.DataBinding

End Sub
```

It works for me, and I'm binding everything to OpenAccess.